# What is a context in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I'm trying to understand the concept of context and context processor.

- What is a context and why do you use it?
- Is a context a value you need to have available in order to use in a template?
- Is a context and a context processor the same?

Comment: @JosephVictorZammit your link holds no mention of context ||| see instead --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

When you use a Django Template, it is compiled once (and only once) and stored for future use, as an optimization. A template can have variable names in double curly braces, such as 
`{{ myvar1 }}` and `{{ myvar2 }}`.

A [Context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context) is a dictionary with variable names as the **key** and their values as the **value**. Hence, if your context for the above template looks like: `{myvar1: 101, myvar2: 102}`, when you pass this context to the template render method, `{{ myvar1 }}` would be replaced with `101` and `{{ myvar2 }}` with `102` in your template. This is a simplistic example, but really a Context object is the *context* in which the template is being rendered.

As for a ContextProcessor, that is a slightly advanced concept. You can have in your `settings.py` file listed a few Context Processors which take in an `HttpRequest` object and return a dictionary (similar to the Context object above). The dictionary (context) returned by the Context Processor is merged into the context passed in by you (the user) by Django.

A use case for a Context Processor is when you always want to insert certain variables inside your template (for example the location of the user could be a candidate). Instead of writing code to insert it in each view, you could simply write a context processor for it and add it to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings in `settings.py`.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for taking the class!

Comment: Thanks a lot Sid!. I really appreciate your help and your time! You clarified my doubts about this. I took your class because I'm building an MVP for an Idea I have. So I finish it and went beyond by reading "two scoops of django" but there're a lot of concepts I still don't quite understand. In the answer below I extend what I'm trying to do with this specific app.

Answer (score 22):

A **context** is a **variable name** -> **variable value** mapping that is passed to a template.

**Context processors** let you specify a number of variables that get set in each **context** automatically – without you having to specify the variables in each **render()** call.

Answer (score 6):

The `Context` is described quite well in [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#module-django.template). In short:

1. In day-to-day use, mostly indirectly, because [helper functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) construct the `Context` for you
2. See 1.: you only need it if you use [the low-level api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)
3. No, a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) is a function that takes a request and returns a dictionary of variables that are then available in all templates that are rendered with a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), for example:

   ```
   def get_stuff_from_session(request):
       return {'stuff': request.session['stuff']}
   ```