# Django: How display a different image according to my function in views.py

Tags: python, django, image, view

I would like to display an image in function of my views. For Example if I have value in my database "100" for a user, my website show me a specific Image if the value is not "100" it shows me another Image. I wrote a simple code with "print" but I do not know how replace "print" with an image and then display it on my page.

this my views.py

```
def Test(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        name = coach.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except coach.DoesNotExist:
        name = coach(user=request.user)
    objs = Lesson.objects.all().filter(mycoach = name)
    args = {'objs': objs}
    if name.monday=="100":
        print("Monday")
    else:
        print("Not Monday")
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Welcome to your profile')
    return render(request, 'test.html', args)
else:
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: You probably want to use a 'context variable'. They are stored in a 'context' dictionary in your view and then they can be used by your template. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957388/what-is-a-context-in-django

Comment: In your case, your template's context dict is the variable `args`. By convention you might want to rename that 'context'. Add the image file name you want to use in that dict, and then use that image file name in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

```
def Test(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        name = coach.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except coach.DoesNotExist:
        name = coach(user=request.user)
    objs = Lesson.objects.all().filter(mycoach = name)
    args = {'objs': objs}
    if name.monday=="100":
       args['image_url'] = 'https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg' 
    else:
        args['image_url'] = 'http://cdn1.itpro.co.uk/sites/itpro/files/styles/article_main_wide_image/public/images/dir_248/it_photo_124192.jpg?itok=ey4UVXkQ'
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Welcome to your profile')
    return render(request, 'test.html', args)
else:
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

> home.html

```
{% if image_url %}
    <img src="{{image_url}}" alt=""/>
{% endif %}
```

relace image urls with your's.