# Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django, django-views

Help, i am seeing the error above and i have tried many edits to no avail.

```
  #template   
  <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
    <h1><a href="{% url 'details' pk=Testimony.pk %}">{{Testimony.Title}}</h1>
  </header>

    #my urls
    re_path('<int:pk>/', views.detail.as_view(), name='details'),



    #my views.py
   class detail(DetailView):
    model = Testimony
    template= 'details.html'

    def TestimonyDetailView(request, pk):
        Testimony = get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'Testimony': Testimony})
```

Comment: `return render(request, self.template, context={'Testimony': Testimony})` you're not passing `Jeans` to your context. Try this: `context={'Jeans': Jeans, 'Testimony': Testimony}. Your template does not know what Jeans.pk is if you don't pass the variable Jeans to your context

Comment: Are your urls namespaced properly?
If they are within an app, you may have to use app_name:url_name in template url

Comment: Seemingly so. My other urls work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a variable coming from a view to templates, you need to send it through a context.

In your case, `Jean` as a variable is not present in the template since you did not send it via the context `context={'Testimony': Testimony}`.

to solve it you need it to add a key to the dict(context) representing the variable as a string.

```
return render(request, self.template, context = {'Jean':Jean,'Testimony': Testimony})
```

NOTE that you can send variables through `context_processors` as well.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958082/5644965) will help you understand the process.

Comment: I just edited my code to the above. Still seeing the same error. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Error: Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['<int:pk>\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', '<int:pk>/']. It points to the line in my template above.

Comment: wow you are using CBV, you need to send the variable via `get_context_processor`. and I am not sure that your view is correct