# Django,html template,for loop not working as expected

Tags: html, django, loops, templates, model

I am trying to apply a for loop to the following html (in a Django project) such that the 'Name' and the 'Comments' field are caused to repeat on the html view.

When I insert the templating code, that is:

```
{% for c in comments %}
{% endfor %}
```

on either side of the content i want to repeat, it simply makes the name and comments disappear altogether and does not have the desired result.

The relevant parts of the file are below:

**index.html (the main html page)**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'guestbook/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<h1>The world's guestbook</h1>
<p><a href="{% url 'sign' %}">Sign </a>the guestbook</p>
{% for c in comments %}
<h2>Name</h2>


<p>This the message that the user leaves.</p>

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py (in the guestbook app)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Comment

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context ={'comments': comments}
    #name=Name.objects.order_by('-date_added')

    return render(request,'guestbook/index.html')


def sign(request):
    return render(request,'guestbook/sign.html')
```

**models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Comment(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comment=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am working off a tutorial in which this is the recommended code and the desired result is as expected - I notice my html template does not have div tags and wonder if that could be an issue? If so, how can it be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that context:

```
def index(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context ={'comments': comments}
    return render(request,'guestbook/index.html', context=context)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From [documentation of render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

> **Context:** A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is
>   callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

Meaning, the values inside dictionary which is being used with known argument `context` of render function, these values will be sent to the template. Then you can access those values through `{{ key }}` of the dictionary(which is sent as context) in html template, or your case `{{ comments }}`. More information can be found regarding context in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957388/what-is-a-context-in-django).

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or link that helps a complete beginner understand the best practices and easiest way to use templates (e.g. something simple like making the customised text input boxes with their css become functional, with the {{form}} command.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest, but i think you can follow django's official tutorial or django girl's, or YouTube videos.