# How to display data Today, Yesterday and last 7 Days in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

I want to display data of `today`, `yesterday` and last `7 days`, please let me know how I can do it.

I am trying this....but it's displaying me only the last 7 days data, but I want to display data in my HTML file according to `today`, `yesterday` and `last 7 days`
here is my `views.py` file..

```
def myview(request):
  datas= Mymodel.objects.filter(created_on_gte=datetime.now()- 
  timedelta(days=7)).count()
  context= {'datas':datas}
  return render(request, 'test.html', context}
```

here is my `test.html` file, where I am displaying data...

```
<p>{{datas}} today</p>
<p>{{datas}} Yesterday</p>
<p>{{datas}} Last 7 Days</p>
```

Comment: What is the field type of `created_on` ? `DateField` or `DateTimeField`?

Comment: it's a `DateTimeField` field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give an aggregated result and use it appropriately in the template

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models

now = timezone.now()
Mymodel.objects.aggregate(
    today=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date=now.date())),
    yesterday=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date__gte=(now - timedelta(hours=24)).date())),
    last_7_day=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date__gte=(now - timedelta(days=7)).date())),
)
```

### UPDATE

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


def myview(request):
    now = timezone.now()
    result = Mymodel.objects.aggregate(
        total=models.Count('id'),
        today=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date=now.date())),
        yesterday=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date__gte=(now - timedelta(hours=24)).date())),
        last_7_day=models.Count('id', filter=models.Q(created_on__date__gte=(now - timedelta(days=7)).date())),
    )
    context = {'result': result}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

then in your template,

```
<p>{{ result.today }} today</p>
<p>{{ result.yesterday }} Yesterday</p>
<p>{{ result.last_7_day }} Last 7 Days</p>
```

Comment: how i will display on my html according to `today`, `yesterday` and `last 7 days`

Comment: pass the data into template as context variables.

Comment: [What is context in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957388/what-is-a-context-in-django)

Comment: i updated my questing with views, please check and let me know

Comment: it's giving me `0` results in all `today`, `yesterday` and `last 7 days`

Comment: check your data in DB

Comment: could you please solve this issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025282/how-to-pass-csrf-token-in-django-ajax

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def days(request):
    
    week = Mymodel.objects.filter(created_on_gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7)).count()
    yesterday = Mymodel.objects.filter(created_on_gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).count()
    today = Mymodel.objects.filter(created_on_gte=datetime.now())

    context = {
        'week': week,
        'yesterday' : yesterday,
        'today' : today,
    }
return render(request, 'days.html', context)
```

.html

```
<p>{{today}} today</p>
<p>{{yesterday}} Yesterday</p>
<p>{{week}} Last 7 Days</p>
```