# How do these different Django 'context' construction differ?

Tags: django, django-context

The basic concept of `context` in Django are well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958082/5965865) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957890/5965865), as well as Django doc. But I don't understand the following code that works in the [Mozilla Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views):

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['author_books'] = Book.objects.filter(author=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

Why is it necessary to define `context` twice? Is it the same as:
author_books =    # 'author_books' defined
book_list =      # 'book_list' defined

```
    context ={
        'author_books': author_books,
        'book_list': book_list,
    }
```

Testing in Django shell didn't work for me as I'm still struggling with how to extract data from foreign-key items.

Comment: It's not defined twice, the get_context_data method from the base class generic.ListView is overriden to add an extra entry named 'author_books', that is computed based on the 'pk' parameter of the HTTP request

Comment: So is the first `context` not necessary? Do you suppose it is just an example the Tutorial gives?

Comment: No, in the first line you initialize the variable context to what the parent class ListView returns: a dict with some entries.